# How can I force a Browser to re-cache a Website?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, caching, joomla

We did a very big Update on our Website and now we have issues with some of our Clients that the CSS broke. We need to implement a way to refresh the Browser Cache. We are also not able to add a version to the end of the Files.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the headers...

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

They must be before any output

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I was trying to put a funny spin on it.. I guess it's hard to get thru text only. You are right my answer should be more explanatory...